# Truffle compiles different binary than RemixIde, even with same compiler version and evm version

Tags: truffle, remix, compiler, truffle-compile

The code:

```
pragma solidity <0.9.0;

contract Callee {
    address public a;
    address public b;
 
    function test(uint256 i) public returns(uint256){
        a=address(this);
        b=msg.sender;
        return i+1;
    }
}
```

After compiled by Remix and Truffle, the numbers after `PUSH` are different.

[image]

Environment:

1. Remix:

- compiler: 0.8.13+commit.abaa5c0e
- evm version: london
- 'enable optimization' unchecked
- run environment: Javascript VM (London)

2. Truffle:

- compiler: native solc 0.8.13+commit.abaa5c0e.Linux.g++

```
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "native", 
       settings: { 
        optimizer: {
          enabled: false,
          //runs: 200
        },
        evmVersion: "london"
       }
    }
  },
```

What causes the difference?

Comment: Remove <0.9.0 and use exactly pragma solidity 0.8.13